# If a matrix satisfies $U+U^T\geq 0$, does its unitarily similar counterpart also satisfy the inequality?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

If a real $n\times n$ matrix $U$ satisfies $U+U^T\geq 0$ (i.e., positive semi-definite), does its unitarily similar counterpart $V = W U W^T$, with $WW^T = W^T W = I$, also satisfy $V+V^T \geq 0$?

Comment: Shouldn't the transformation be $WUW^\dagger$ for unitary similarity?

Comment: By $A \geq 0$, do you mean that $A$ is positive semidefinite or that $A$ has positive entries?

Comment: @BenGrossmann positive semidefinite - it is stated in the question =)

Comment: @BenGrossmann By $\geq 0$, I mean positive semidefinite. Also, the matrices $U,V,W$ are not symmetric.

Comment: By the way, $W$ is not required to be unitary for this to hold. It also works for an arbitrary linear operators (such that $W U W^*$ makes sense) -- see the answer of Fred below.

Comment: @NDewolf By $W^\dagger$, you mean pseudo inverse? I am following the definition of unitary similarity as in Chapter 2 of Matrix Analysis by Horn and Johnson.

Comment: By $\dagger$ I meant the Hermitian adjoint, which is also often (as in the book) denoted by an asterisk $*$.

Comment: Oh ok. All matrices are real.  That is, the unitary similarity is same as the unitary congruence in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $V+V^{T}=W(U+U^{T})W^{T}.$ It follows that

$$((V+V^{T})x|x)=((U+U^{T})W^{T}x|W^{T}x) \ge 0.$$

Comment: Actually, $V+V^T = WUW^T + W^T U^T W$. The matrices $U,V,W$ are not symmetric.

Comment: @unobservable_node $(ABC)^T = C^T B^T A^T$, you do not need the matrices to be symmetric.

Comment: @observable_note: If $V=WUW^T$, then $V^T=W^{TT}U^TW^T=WU^TW^T.$

Comment: Yeah, you are right :) ... I don't know what I was confused about. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Fred Does this also hold for general similar matrices, i.e., $V=WUW^{-1}$?

Comment: See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/834450/452113