# What's the relation between $A=[a_{ij}]\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B=[b_{ij}]$, where $b_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}}{(a_{ii}a_{jj})^\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite and have positive diagonal entries. Show that the matrix $B=[b_{ij}]$ is positive semidefinite, where $b_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}}{(a_{ii}a_{jj})^\frac{1}{2}}$?

At the beginning, I was trying to find the relation between the diagonal entries and eigenvalues of a symmetric to solve it, but I didn't find it. Then I think maybe there is a way to write the matrix $B$ into some form with $A$, but I failed to do it. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: This seems like it should be trivial just from the definition. Have you tried forgetting all that eigenvalue stuff and just showing that $\sum_i\sum_j\lambda_i\lambda_jb_{ij}\ge0$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial from the *definition*  of PSD. Since $A$ is PSD, for any choice of $(\lambda_j)$ we have $$\sum_j\sum_k\lambda_j\lambda_kb_{jk}
=\sum\sum\omega_j\omega_ka_{jk}\ge0,$$where $\omega_j=\lambda_j/\sqrt{a_{jj}}$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint.* $B=D^{-1}AD^{-1}$ where $D=\operatorname{diag}(a_{11}^{1/2},\ldots,a_{nn}^{1/2})$.

Comment: How does that help???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $B$ is PSD because it is congruent to the PSD matrix $A$.

Comment: Assuming "congruent" is the same as "similar": Huh??? If you'd said $B=DAD^{-1}$ or $B=D^{-1}AD$ then yes...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No. Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are congruent if $B=P^\ast AP$ for some nonsingular matrix $P$. Congruent Hermitian matrices have the same indices of inertia, by Sylvester's law of inertia.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you should be aware that similarity transforms in general **do not** preserve positive (semi)definiteness while congruence transforms always do.  See e.g. here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3798668/if-a-matrix-u-satisfy-uut-geq-0-positive-semidefinite-does-its-similar/

Comment: Right. Once it was clear that what you wrote wasn't just a typo or something it didn't take long to figure that out...